# How do I add a ranking number to my tuples?

Tags: scala

My data:

```
(John, 23)
(Micheal, 8)
(Kathy, 8)
(Sam, 18)
```

I need to sort them by value followed by key. Then, I need to assign an order number for them:

```
(0, John, 23)
(1, Sam, 18)
(2, Kathy, 8)
(3, Micheal, 8)
```

This is my current code, data contains the tuples:

```
data.sortBy(x => (-x._2, x._1))
```

I'm not sure how to add the rankings to the front

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with [zipWithIndex](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/Seq.html#zipWithIndex).